# Modifying SubModules

Tags: android, git, github, git-submodules

I have a project I am working on. I use a library that is on GitHub. Normally I have been using this library via Maven. However there are some bugs in the library so I would like to include this library in my repo so I can modify it. I then build the library myself.

What is the best strategy for this? I have tried using sub modules, however [this](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-submodule.html) explains that it is not possible to modify the library in this way.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are wanting to make your own changes to the library, create a copy of the repository (fork) to make your changes in.  This way, your changes can be committed, pushed to the server and if warranted, shared with the original repository.

Bring this new repository into your project the same way you have been for the original.

Comment: Well I was using maven for the original. This automatically uses the production repo. I don't care to push the updates, infact the update are ready to go into development, other developers have submitted them. I just want to use the library in my project